# Python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x91

Tags: python, csv, character-encoding, python-2.x

I'm parsing a CSV as follows:

```
with open(args.csv, 'rU') as csvfile:
        try:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
            for row in reader:
            ...
```

where `args.csv` is the name of my file.  One of the rows in my file is an e with two dots on top.  My script breaks when it encounters this.

I get the following stack trace:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
```

and the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 5: invalid start byte
```

FWIW, I'm running Python 2.7 and upgrading isn't an option (for a few reasons).

I'm pretty lost about how to fix this so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What if you try `with open(args.csv, 'rU', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:` ?

Comment: You could add some data from the csv file maybe as hexdump. Could it be the file is not meaningfully interpretable as utf8 because it was encoded to bytes from some windows or other encodings?

Comment: The dots are called an [umlaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic))

Comment: The error doesn't come from the code, it comes from call to `json.dumps`

Comment: and you should mention the Python 2.7 as a *tag*.

Comment: To handle your cp1252-encoded data please see the [Examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) at the end of the CSV docs. Also, in Python 2 you should open csv files in binary mode, as mentioned near the start of those docs.

Answer (score 11):

Byte 0x91 is a "smart" opening single quote in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding. So it sounds like that's the encoding your file is using, not UTF-8. So, use `open(args.csv, 'rU', encoding='windows-1252')`.

Comment: When I follow your answer, I get: "TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function".  Fwiw, I'm running Python 2.7 and (for a few reasons) can't change that.

Comment: @bclayman It is preferable that you mention that in your question, even though it is mentioned in the stacktrace.

Comment: Great answer! I managed to convert a file in Uzbek language to UTF-8 `iconv -t UTF-8 -f Windows-1252 in.xml` I would've spent a lot of time guessing what 0x91 and 0x92 character mean.