# How to address: Python import of file with .csv Dictreader fails on undefined character

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv

First of all, I found [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019379/python-unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x91) which is basically the same as my question, but it is closed and I'm not sure I understand the reason for closing vs. the content of the post.  I also don't really see a working answer.

I have 20+ input files from 4 apps.  All files are exported as .csv files.  The first 19 files worked (4 others exported from the same app work) and then I ran into a file that gives me this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 5762: character maps to <undefined>
```

If I looked that up right it is a &lt ctrl &gt. The code below are the relevant lines:

```
with open(file, newline = '') as f: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect = 'excel')
    for line in reader:
```

I know I'm going to be getting a file.  I know it will be a .csv.  There may be some variance in what I get due to the manual generation/export of the source files.  There may also be some strange characters in some of the files (e.g. Japanese, Russian, etc.). I provide this information because going back to the source to get a different file might just kick the can down the road until I have to pull updated data (or worse, someone else does).

So the question is probably multi-part:
1) Is there a way to tell the csv.DictReader to ignore undefined characters?  (Hint for the codec:  if I can't see it, it is of no value to me.)

2) If I do have "crazy" characters, what should I do?  I've considered opening each input as a binary file, filtering out offending hex characters, writing the file back to disk and then opening the new file, but that seems like a lot of overhead for the program and even more for me.  It's also a few JCL statements from being 1977 again.

3) How do I figure out what I'm getting as an input if it crashes while I'm reading it in.

4) I chose the "dialect = 'excel'"; because many of the inputs are Excel files that can be downloaded from one of the source applications.  From the docs on dictreader, my impression is that this just defines delimiter, quote character and EOL characters to expect/use.  Therefore, I don't think this is my issue, but I'm also a Python noob, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750843/python-3-unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9d#30751201

Comment: This issue is often seen when the environment is reading files in as ASCII encoded when they're actually UTF-8 (which seems likely since you have non-english language characters in your CSVs). Try updating the code to specify the text encoding: `with open(file, newline = '', encoding = 'utf8') as f: `

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.  Just got a different message: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 197: invalid start byte

Comment: I went back to the source file and opened it in Excel.  I did a "save as" to the type .csv (not the unicode variety).  It was already set to that file format, so that answers whether it is Unicode.  The problem is that the data comes from a discovery tool that can pull data from thousands of devices globally.  So there really could be weird stuff in the source file

Comment: Found the answer.  Based on the feedback I decided to look and see if there were other codecs I should try.  In looking through the documentation I found that there is a parameter in open errors='strict'.  It didn't actually say what the other options were, but that led to the right Google search.  This thread is a Duplicate, but not of the thread referenced above.  The correct answer is to open the file with errors='ignore'.  That solved the problem.  This is the thread with the solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487563/unicode-error-handling-with-python-3s-readlines

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Greenstick.  Your edits are much clearer than my initial attempt.

Comment: Happy to help! And welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the solution I went with in the comments above; it was to set the `errors` argument of `open()` to `'ignore'`:

```
with open(file, newline = '', errors='ignore') as f:
```

This is exactly what I was looking for in my first question in the original post above (i.e. whether there is a way to tell the `csv.DictReader` to ignore undefined characters).

Update:  Later I did need to work with some of the Unicode characters and couldn't ignore them.  The correct answer for that solution based on Excel-produced unicode .csv file was to use the 'utf_8_sig' codec.  That deletes the byte order marker (utf-16 BOM) that Windows writes at the top of the file to let it know there are unicode characters in it.