# Python importing .csv files in utf-8 or cp1252

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file-io, utf-8

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087219/how-to-address-python-import-of-file-with-csv-dictreader-fails-on-undefined-ch/52088173#52088173) a while back about dealing with import of .csv files with special characters.  At the time I was interested in solving the 90% case, but now I'm back for the last 10%.

It's mostly the same setup as before:

1. Many input files
2. All .csv
3. New: Now I want to preserve special characters in some inputs.  However, I don't have control over the format of all of my input files, so I have a mix of files that I need to process.  My attempt at the solution was to pass a keyword argument when I want to do a different encoding format.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import unicodecsv
#<Lots of other declarations and initialization>

def _csv_dict(self, file,index_field, ScrubMe, **kwargs):

#some irrelevant initialization stuff here.

    if 'formatting' in kwargs:
        formatting = kwargs['formatting']
    else:
        formatting =  None #cp1252 is OS default

    with open(file, encoding=formatting, errors='ignore') as f: #newline = '',
        if formatting == None:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect = 'excel')
        else: #assume for now UTF-8 is the only other supported format
            reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f, dialect = csv.excel)

        for line in reader:
            <do some stuff - it's mostly building dictionaries, but I
generally edit the data to only keep the stuff I care about and do a little
data transformation to standard formats >
```

The result of the above is that if I pass an Excel file saved as a .CSV in native codec, the import works.  However, the unicodecsv file with call including formatting='utf-8' keyword arg crashes

The error message suggests that I'm passing the wrong type of object somewhere along the line.  This happens the first time I attempt to read a line out of the UTF-8 file

```
File 
"C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-
packages\unicodecsv\py3.py", line 51, in <genexpr>
f = (bs.decode(encoding, errors=errors) for bs in f)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

From what I have read, UTF-8 is actually tab-separated instead of comma-separated, but I "think" it's supposed to work the same way.

I feel like I've probably messed up something pretty simple, but I've killed enough time looking that it seems appropriate to ask for help.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Well, I made a little progress.  The bs.decode() in the error message was apparently not about Python being able to decode the BS I asked it to execute.  It wanted me to open the file in binary mode.  I still don't have it working.  I'm getting a key error.  It appears there is a little header info at the top of the file and the unicode csvReader isn't handling it right.

Comment: The header turns out to be a UTF-16 byte order marker.  This has me confused because I asked Excel to save as UTF-8 .csv.  I tried just reading the two-byte header, but it apparently expects a header to be there and errors with an unexpected byte.  I tried opening as a text file with UTF-16 encoding setting for the reader.  That turned all of my text to unreadable.  So far the closest to correct is if the open is open (file, 'rb') and the encoding on the reader is 'utf-8', but it mangles my first key with the BOM.

Comment: You don't need `unicodecsv` in Python 3. The std-lib `csv` module works with (Unicode) strings here.

Comment: My source file is Excel with a "save-as .csv UTF-8".  Perhaps I did something wrong, but if I use the standard .csv, it mangles the first key because of the BOM.   I'll bet it would work if the data was saved from a text editor instead of Excel.  Ironically, Excel doesn't re-ingest this data very well.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to hear that Excel is bad at properly decoding text data. However, this is completely unrelated to the fact that you don't need to (or even shouldn't) use the `unicodecsv` package if you're using Python 3. Open the files in text mode with the right encoding and everything should pass smooth through the std-lib `csv` module (provided you don't have corrupt data).

Comment: OK, I tried opening in text mode (utf_8 codec instead of utf_8_sig).  I just did it for my output.  It actually runs through a lot of the file and then it finds a Russian guy named Контур. It chokes on his first name.  It says it charmap can't encode those characters because they map to "undefined".

Comment: Are you trying to `print()` that name? Or are you writing it to some output file? If it says "can't encode", then it's about output, not input.

Comment: @lenz, my question was about input and the only way to make that work was with the utf_8_sig codec.  This codec removes the BOM written by Excel at the start of the file which looks like UTF-16, but the encoding of the data is still UTF-8.  That solved, I was still interested in what you were saying about using dictreader/dictwriter without using the unicode version.  I decided not to mess with my input, but instead work on the writer side to play around with it.  I think the answer is that I can't open it in any format but utf_8_sig, but I can output it in utf_8, which I think will help

Answer (score 3):

I'm replacing my initial answer because I had multiple things going on and it took me a while to untangle them.

1) @lenz is correct.  In Python 3 it is unnecessary to use unicodecsv.DictReader.  Part of what confused me is the difference in implementation.

a) For the older unicodecsv.DictReader from Python 2:

```
kw_args={'errors' : None}
with open(filename, 'rb', **kw_args) as file:
    reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(file, dialect = csv.excel, encoding='utf_8_sig' )
```

b) For Python 3 csv.DictReader

```
kw_args={'newline' : '','errors' : None,'encoding' : 'utf_8_sig'}
with open(filename, 'r', **kw_args) as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, dialect = csv.excel )
```

To summarize the differences

- Mode of file open is now text instead of bytes
- Because of the different open method, the codec can/should be specified in the file open vs. in the DictReader
- newline parameter is also only valid for the file opened as text.

2) Because my UTF-8 file was produced by Excel, it has a utf_16_le style BOM at the top of the file.  The only coded that works for this is 'utf_8_sig'.

3) Because my output files are being read downstream by SQL Server, the output codec needs to be 'utf_16_le' or SQL Server doesn't recognize it.

4) Also, because the target is SQL Server, I have to manually insert the BOM at the top of the file.

```
csvfile.write('\uFEFF') 
writer.writeheader()
```

If you open the above output file in Excel it will no longer be in columns, but SQL Server (actually SSIS) now knows how to read the file.

5) Just to mess with me a little more, someone had '\n' in a few of the records.  With Excel as source and destination, this was not an issue, but it was for SSIS.  My solution:

```
for r in record_list:
    temp={}
    for k,v in r.items():

        if isinstance(v,str):
            temp[k] = v.replace('\n',' ')
        else:
            temp[k] = v
    writer.writerow(temp)
```